# how to style a button after clicking another button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change button 2 to finger pointer after clicking  button 1
so i am wondering is there a way to do it if there is please tell me what code do i write
Note:button 1 is already a finger pointer i want button 2 to be a finger pointer after clicking button 1
this is my code:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" type="submit" style="cursor: pointer; background-color:black;height: 45px; width: 150px; color:red;border-radius:10px;"value="first button" onclick="enableButton2()" /> 
<input type="button" id="button2" style="background-color:yellow; height: 45px;width: 225px;color:red;border-radius:10px;"value="second button" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it :

```
<script>
       function enableButton2(){
           var btn2 = document.getElementById('button2');
           btn2.setAttribute('disabled', false)
           btn2.style.cursor = 'pointer'
       }
   </script>
   
   <input type="button" id="button1" type="submit" style="cursor: pointer; background-color:black;height: 45px; width: 150px; color:red;border-radius:10px;" value="first button" onclick="enableButton2()" /> 
    <input type="button" id="button2" style="background-color:yellow; height: 45px;width: 225px;color:red;border-radius:10px;" value="second button" disabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this way:

the css style you are looking for is `cursor : not-allowed;`

```js
const bt_1 = document.getElementById('button1')
  ,   bt_2 = document.getElementById('button2')
  ;
bt_1.onclick = () =>
  {
  bt_2.disabled = false
  }
```

```css
button {
  cursor        : pointer; 
  height        : 45px; 
  border-radius : 10px;    
  color         : red;
  }
button[disabled] {
  cursor           : not-allowed;
  pointer-events   : none;
  color            : #c0c0c0;
  background-color : #ffffff !important;
  }
#button1 {
  background-color : black;
  width            : 150px; 
  }
#button2 {
  background-color : yellow; 
  width            : 225px;
  }
```

```html
<button id="button1" type="submit" > first button  </button>
<button id="button2"   disabled    > second button </button>
```